# override table-striped first row font

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

css

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td,
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > th {
    background-color: #4289A9;
    font-weight:800;
    color:white;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

html

```
<table class="table table-striped">
 <tr >
   <td class="h6" >text change according to css </td>
   <td class="h6" >text font style not changed  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Using Bootstrap 3. Strangely the first `td` changes according to the CSS but 2nd `td` font style does not change, is the CSS missing something?

Comment: Looks okay - both tds changed.  You might need to reload the CSS.

Comment: Found out the problem, was using devexpress and it was overriding the css when using the ASPxLabel, change it and it is ok now